# Как сортировать выходные данные в порядке возрастания?

Tags: php

Как сортировать выходные данные в порядке возрастания?

```
$dir = "./radio/radio_stantion/";
$name = scandir($dir);
for($i=2; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
....
$fopen=file( $dir.$name[$i] );
$sss = $finalname."---".$http[0]."---".$port[0];
echo $name[$i]." : ".$sss."<br/>";
```

echo выводит:

```
1.txt : nnn ---111 
10.txt : mmm ---222
100.txt : ttt ---333
```

нужно:

```
1.txt : nnn ---111 
2.txt : ввв ---222
3.txt : ссс ---333
...
10.txt : mmm ---222
```

Comment: `usort()` с функцией сравнения и регэксом для получения номера

Comment: Прошу подробнее. Если возможно с примером.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php  — подробнее и с пример**ами**

Comment: еще можно просто `.txt` удалить из имен, сложить с ключами в массива и `ksort` сделать

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию сортировки [natsort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.natsort.php), которая применяет алгоритм "natural order".

Пример:

```
<?php
$arr = scandir(__DIR__);
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($arr);
natsort($arr);
print_r($arr);
echo "</pre>\n";
```

Comment: `$sort = natsort ($name[$i]." : ".$sss."<br/>");
echo $sort;` -?

Comment: Нет. В примере явно показано, какой массив сортирует функция.

Comment: Пробовал: `$name = scandir($dir); $name = natsort ($name);` - не идет.